# Yesterdays Date in Batch File

Tags: dos, batch-file

I need a script in batch file which will get me yesterdays date into a variable when i run it. Including the conditions like march 1st(which will be Feb 28th or 29th depending on the yr)

Comment: Do you know how to get *today's* date in a batch file?

Comment: What environment is this?  What type of batch file?  Could it be run with parameters passed in?  What is the context?

Comment: @Frustrated yes i do....

Comment: @Wllmsaccnt.........it should take todays date as input(automatically i mean with out passing manually) and return yest's date...

Comment: Retagged your question with .bat and ms-dos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a ms-dos batch file, see [this page](http://www.powercram.com/2010/07/get-yesterdays-date-in-ms-dos-batch.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Perl, try [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=88053).